# Nesting Python kwargs

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Is nesting kwargs in dictionaries a harmful thing to do? I've used this technique a few times, mainly when I have a long chain of callers and seek to avoid having to change all of their arguments if I make one change deep in the list of callers. What is a safer alternative (e.g., misspelling `baz_kwargs` in the `bar_kwargs` dictionary will fail silently) that lets me maintain some ease of configurability ?

```
def baz(mx, n = 10, delim = '|'):
    print '{}'.format(delim).join([str(mx)]*n)

def bar(mx, double = False, baz_kwargs = {}, **my_kwargs):
    if double:
        mx *= 2
    baz(mx, **baz_kwargs)

def foo(a, b = 1, bar_kwargs = {}):
    bar(b * a, **bar_kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bar_kwargs = {'double' : True,
              'baz_kwargs' : {'delim' : '|'}}
     foo(10, b = 2, bar_kwargs = bar_kwargs)
```

Comment: It breaks encapsulation since the caller is expected to know not only the signature being called, but the signature of an internal function call.

Comment: `bar_kwargs = {}` is a bad idea alone.

Comment: @TomDalton True. I clarified the question: What is an alternative that lets me maintain the configurability of this approach (not having to modify much along the chain of callers), while being 'safer'?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: In this context the mutable default argument is not harmful, since none of the functions modify the dictionaries they're passed. It is something to be very careful of though.

Comment: @Blckknght, I have no idea what the OP is actually doing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection would be one way to avoid passing the internal parameters as part of the external call.